# Data from a custom Google Map

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to collect data from this page
xxx

My experience level with python and BeautifulSoup is beginner. However I don't think that it has to be very advanced for what I need to do, excepting for the issue that I am describing below

The page that I need to collect data from lists the active properties for sale listed on MLS for the Greater Toronto Area.
At the right side of the map there are some checkboxes that you must select in order to get your data and this is where my problem is. If I use a browser a local cookie is used to remember the previous selections and tha data is displayed

I would like to know either of these:
1) how I can pass all the params (selections) in my initial request from Python
2) how to use the Chrome cookie with Python so I can get a page return that actually contains data

A code example would be great but sending me to links that I should read would also work.

Thanks a lot
PF

Comment: look at the `requests` library for fetching the pages.  it has much better cookie support than `urllib2` .  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using urllib2 over [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), I suggest looking into [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html).

Here is an example:

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar),
)
```

This way you're creating a `cookiejar` to hold cookies, building an opener and establishing your cookie processor and passing `cookiejar`. This should take care of your cookie issue. At this point, instead of using `urllib2.urlopen(url)`, just use your custom opener: `opener.open(url)`

```
url = 'http://www.somesite.com/'
fp = opener.open(url)
html_object = BeautifulSoup(fp)
```